# craeting a dynamic listindex

Tags: vba, combobox

First timer. Learning VBA on the go and need some help. I get an invalid property value on this line of code `Me.Tech2.ListIndex = startnr`

The startnr changes according to value of combobox "Tech2".

```
Dim jobnr As String
Dim startnr As Integer
Dim endnr As Integer

'Tech2 combobox populates according to the name in Tech1 combobox where the name is a named range

jobnr = Tech1.Value
Sheets("Lists").Activate        'named range scope are sheets("Lists")'
Me.Tech2.RowSource = jobnr
endnr = 10000

 If Me.Tech2 = "" Then
     For startnr = 1 To endnr
     Next startnr
 End If

Me.Tech2.ListIndex = startnr
```

Answer (score 0):

`startnr` is `10001` so `Me.Tech2.ListIndex = startnr` tries to make the selected item the 10,002nd item in `Tech2`, if that item does not exist the error is raised.

Valid values for `ListIndex` are `0` for the first item through `Me.Tech2.ListCount - 1` for the last item.